# CakeDC Users Plugin: Disable/Override Username Validation

Tags: plugins, cakedc, cakephp-3.1

How to configure CakeDC's Users plugin to **override/disable** the **username** field?

I have reconfigured the plugin to use 'email' field as username for login - and it works great for login - but I no longer need the username field validation in the registration.

Any ideas? Thanks!

*Using CakePHP 3.1 and CakeDC User plugin 3.1.3*

Answer (score 2):

You can override the Users table and configure your own validation rules, etc following this page in the documentation https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.1.x/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md#extending-the-model-tableentity

Once you are done with the new Table, don't forget to pass the new table configuration to Users Plugin Configuration using the parameter

```
'Users.table' => 'MyUsers',
```

The plugin was built with extension in mind. You should be able to extend/override any feature in your project.

Please feel free to open a ticket here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues if you find something we could improve.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to extend also controller? or is it enough extend only models? I tried all with controller (including modifying routes to new controller), all works (login, profile, registration), but the routing of LOGOUT action is failing... user is logged-out, but is redirected to "users/app-users/login" (AppUsers is my table model), and this url does not exists...any idea?

Comment: ok, solved, once I submitted this :) I was not overriding correctly the plugin value in custom config users.php.  
`...'Auth' => [
      'loginAction' => [
          'plugin' => null, /*needs to be overrided to null*/
          'controller' => 'AppUsers',
          'action' => 'login',
      ],...`

Comment: Hi, is Steinkel valid or is there any way to make username not used for longin by web or social networks ..? My idea is that there is no username in the model since I identified by email and password.

Comment: You can keep the username and let the social login manage it internally, then use only the email in your application. Please submit a ticket in github if you need a different use case but having a username at least internally could help you, for example when users are updating their emails.